# Is there a function to lock column from being modified using Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I want to lock certain column to prevent user edit the data of the column. Is **Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel** provide this feature ?

What I have tried,

```
$sheet->setFreeze('A2');
```

But, it doesn't work. Is my method wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used `setFreeze()` method but it doesn't work for my case as well.

I have thought this problem in different way and here is the way,

1. Protect whole sheet.
2. Now remove protection for areas which need writable access. i.e. **except A**

Here is the code.

```
$sheet->loadView('template');
$sheet->getProtection()->setPassword('password');
$sheet->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
```

Now unprotect the areas,

```
$sheet->getStyle('B1:D100')->getProtection()->setLocked(PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED);
```

Column A will be protected already since whole sheet is protected, so remove protection from column B to last column.

In this case rectangular area from B1 to D100 will be editable. You can customize according to your requirement.

Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Hole Sheet Protection

```
$sheet->loadView('template');
$sheet->getProtection()->setPassword('password');
$sheet->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
```

Remove Work area Protection

```
$sheet->getStyle('B4:F100')->getProtection()->setLocked(\PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED);
```